# Remove black paddings in List (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, list, listview, swiftui, padding

This is code of my List:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PaymentScreen: View {

    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
        UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .black // I can change color of this paddings here
    }

    var body: some View {
        return VStack (alignment: .center) {
            List (Terminal.terminals, id: \.self.distance) { terminal in
                PayTerminalAdapter(terminal: terminal).background(Color.white)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot of my list:

[image]

I can't remove black leading and trailing paddings and paddings between list elements. When I use ForEach (I have very long array of terminals) - i don't have problem with paddings, but it works so slowly, therefore ForEach is a bad choice for me. How can i remove black paddings in List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for the `.listRowInsets` modifier.

**Solution:**

```
List {
    ForEach(Terminal.terminals, id: \.self.distance) {
        PayTerminalAdapter(terminal: terminal).background(Color.white)
    }
    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 1, leading: 2, bottom: 1, trailing: 2))
}
```

In the above, you may have noticed that the `List(data:)` is now simply `List(content:)`, and the data is moved to a `ForEach(data:id:)`.
I am not sure if there is a SwiftUI bug but `.listRowInsets` works only on single items. This single item can then have multiple items though and still be reusable, so no worries.
However, just as a test, even though the following looks like it should work, it does not:

**Example (not working):**

```
List(0...100, id: \.self) { _ in
    Text("Custom row inset not being applied")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 1, leading: 2, bottom: 1, trailing: 2))
}
```

So put your datasource in a `ForEach` and apply `.listRowInsets` on it.

**Example (working):**

```
List {
    ForEach(0...100, id: \.self) { _ in
        Text("Custom row inset being applied")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color.gray)
    }
    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 1, leading: 2, bottom: 1, trailing: 2))
}
```

Comment: Good! It works! But anyway interesting, why .listRowInsets() don't work, when i use only List, without ForEach?

Comment: @alexbayker I am not sure, it may be a bug with the way `List(data:id:)` internally works. If I do figure it out, I will update this answer. If this answer has helped, then kindly accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

You should change `.listRowBackground()` for that.

Comment: Yes, i know about .listRowBackground(). It's not so easy.

Comment: What is the issue then? Tell me so I can see if I can help you more

Comment: UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .white - i change color of this paddings, but can't remove it

Comment: take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58592055/5623035)

Comment: I know about changing color of this padding, but i want to remove it

Comment: Honestly, I don't get what do you want. Do you mean the `separator`?

Comment: I want to change size of this padding to 0. Without changing color.